# Detect 0 rows in a Telerik ASP.NET MVC Grid

Tags: grid, telerik-mvc

What is considered the best practice for determining whether there are any rows bound?

Currently, I'm using the client-side OnDataBound event, and code similar to the following:

```
gridDataBound: function (event)
{
   var rows = $('tbody tr:has(td)', this);
   if (rows.length == 0 || (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].innerText == "No records to display'))
      $('#GridSection').hide("slow");
}
```

There has got to be a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a shorter version:

```
 if ($(this).find(".t-no-data").length) {
    $("#GridSection").hide("slow");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, a few minutes poking around and I think I have a solution that really feels better-

```
if ($("tbody tr:has(td).t-no-data", this).length != 0) {
   $("#GridSection").hide("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#grid-name').data('tGrid').data` is an array of all of the records.

So, you can get the number of records using:

```
$('#grid-name').data('tGrid').data.length;
```

Comment: unless there are no records.  in that case, `data` is undefined